# Rust How do you define a default method for similar types?

Tags: arrays, rust, casting, traits

A very common pattern I have to deal with is, I am given some raw byte data. This data can represent an array of floats, 2D vectors, Matrices...

I know the data is compact and properly aligned. In C usually you would just do:

vec3 * ptr = (vec3*)data;

And start reading from it.

I am trying to create a view to this kind of data in rust to be able to read and write to the buffer as follows:

```rust
pub trait AccessView<T>
{
    fn access_view<'a>(
        offset : usize,
        length : usize,
        buffer : &'a Vec<u8>) -> &'a mut [T]
    {
        let bytes = &buffer[offset..(offset + length)];
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr() as *mut T;
        return unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, length / size_of::<T>()) };
    }
}
```

And then calling it:

```rust
   let data: &[f32] =
        AccessView::<f32>::access_view(0, 32, &buffers[0]);
```

The idea is, I should be able to replace `f32` with `vec3` or `mat4` and get a slice view into the underlying data.

This is crashing with:

```
   --> src/main.rs:341:9
    |
341 |         AccessView::<f32>::access_view(&accessors[0], &buffer_views, &buffers);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `_: AccessView<f32>`
```

How could I use rust to achieve my goal? i.e. have a generic "template" for turning a set of raw bytes into a range checked slice view casted to some type.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is `&buffers[0]`?

Comment: Also, AccessView is a `trait`, not a `struct`. You can't just directly call `trait` functions (to my knowledge) without having an actual type connected to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two important problems I can identify:

- You are using a `trait` incorrectly. You have to connect a `trait` to an actual type. If you want to call it the way you do, it needs to be a `struct` instead.
- [Soundness](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). You are creating a mutable reference from an immutable one through `unsafe` code. This is unsound and dangerous. By using `unsafe`, you tell the compiler that you manually verified that your code is `sound`, and the borrow checker should blindly believe you. Your code, however, is **not sound**.

To part 1, @BlackBeans gave you a good answer already. I would still do it a little differently, though. I would directly imlement the trait for `&[u8]`, so you can write `data.access_view::<T>()`.

To part 2, you at least need to make the input data `&mut`. Further, make sure they have the same lifetime, otherwise the compiler might not realize that they are actually connected.

Also, don't use `&Vec<u8>` as an argument; in general, use [slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) (`&[u8]`) instead.

Be aware that with all that said, there still is the problem of **ENDIANESS**. The behavior you will get will **not be consistent** between platforms. Use other means of conversion instead if that is something you require. Do not put this code in a generic library, at max use it for your own personal project.

That all said, here is what I came up with:

```
pub trait AccessView {
    fn access_view<'a, T>(&'a mut self, offset: usize, length: usize) -> &'a mut [T];
}

impl AccessView for [u8] {
    fn access_view<T>(&mut self, offset: usize, length: usize) -> &mut [T] {
        let bytes = &mut self[offset..(offset + length)];
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr() as *mut T;
        return unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, length / ::std::mem::size_of::<T>()) };
    }
}

impl AccessView for Vec<u8> {
    fn access_view<T>(&mut self, offset: usize, length: usize) -> &mut [T] {
        self.as_mut_slice().access_view(offset, length)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    println!("{:?}", data);

    let float_view: &mut [f32] = data.access_view(2, 4);
    float_view[0] = 42.0;
    println!("{:?}", float_view);

    println!("{:?}", data);

    // println!("{:?}", float_view);   // Adding this would cause a compiler error, which shows that we implemented lifetimes correctly
}
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[42.0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 40, 66, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't understood exactly what traits are. Traits represent a characteristic of a type, for instance, since I know the size at compile-time of `u32` (32 bits), `u32` *implements* the marker trait `Sized`, noted `u32: Sized`. A more feature-complete trait could be the `Default` one: if there is a "default" way of building of type `T`, then we can implement `Default` for it, so that now there is a standard default way of building it.

In your example, you are using a trait as a namespace for functions, ie you could simply have

```rust
fn access_view<'a, T>(
    offset: usize,
    length: usize,
    buffer: &'a [u8]
) -> &'a mut T
{
    let bytes = &buffer[offset..offset+length];
    let ptr = bytes.as_ptr() as *mut T;
    unsafe {
      std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, length / size_of::<T>()
    } 
}
```

Or, if you want to put it as a trait:

```rust
trait Viewable {
    fn access_view<'a>(
        offset: usize,
        length: usize,
        buffer: &'a [u8],
    ) -> &'a mut [Self]
    {
        let bytes = &buffer[offset..offset+length];
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr() as *mut T;
        unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, length / size_of::<T>()
        }
    }
}
```

Then implement it:

```
impl<T> Viewable for T {}
```

Or, again, differently

```rust
trait Viewable {
    fn access_view<'a>(
        offset: usize,
        length: usize,
        buffer: &'a [u8],
    ) -> &'a mut [Self];
}

impl<T> Viewable for T {
    fn access_view<'a>(
        offset: usize,
        length: usize,
        buffer: &'a [u8],
    ) -> &'a mut [Self]
    {
        let bytes = &buffer[offset..offset+length];
        let ptr = bytes.as_ptr() as *mut T;
        unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, length / size_of::<T>()
        }
    }
}
```

Although all this way to structure the code will somehow produce the same result, it doesn't mean they're equivalent. Maybe you should learn a little bit more about traits before using them.

Also, your code, as is, really seems unsound, in the sense that you make a call to an unsafe function without any checking (ie. what if I call it with random nonsense in `buffer`?). It doesn't mean it is (we don't have access to the rest of your code), but you should be careful about that: Rust is not C.

Finally, your error simply comes from the fact that it's impossible for Rust to find out which type `T` you are calling the associated method `access_view` of.